# Orika convert String to Date when map data from HashMap to bean

Tags: orika

I use orika 1.5.2 . when map data from HashMap to bean with convert String to java.util.Date, I get the Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

DateToStringConverter also not take effect. But the exception not come out when I map data from Bean A to Bean B.

How can I convert String to Date when I map data from a Map to bean?

code:

```
public class UserA {
private Date birthday;

public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "UserA [birthday=" + birthday + "]";
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("birthday", "2014-04-28");

    UserA ua = new UserA();
    MapperFactory mapF = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().mapNulls(false).build();
    mapF.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new DateToStringConverter("yyyy-MM-dd"));
    mapF.getMapperFacade().map(map, ua);


}
```

exception:
[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETQ6f.png)

Answer (score 1):

U need Object to Date converter, not DateToStringConverter

user:

```
@Data
public class UserA {
    private Date birthday;
}
```

add Converter

```
public class ObjectToDateConverter extends CustomConverter<Object, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(Object source, Type<? extends Date> destinationType, MappingContext context) {
        if (source instanceof String) {
            try {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).parse((String) source);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

test:

```
@Test
public void testMap(){
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    map.put("birthday", "2018-10-14");
    UserA ua = new UserA();
    MapperFactory mapF = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().mapNulls(false).build();
    mapF.getConverterFactory().registerConverter(new ObjectToDateConverter());
    mapF.getMapperFacade().map(map, ua);
}
```